# Identify missing libraries

Tags: linux, libraries

I downloaded a file with a .gz extension only. It should be a folder with more files inside but when I do

```
$gunzip DOd.gz
```

What I get is a binary file DOd without extensions. If I check what the file is I get

```
$file DOd
DOd: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=dcbc85e17b9e60e67973f488eca1b930b4cd9d9d, not stripped
```

Then it is an executable. But if I try to run it I get:

```
$./DOd
./DOd: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.55.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I then installed the package boost-libs but I get the same error.

Any idea how to make this file run or uncompress?

Comment: It’s not a `gunzip` issue at all. You’re missing libraries. Note the specific version in the filename: 1.55. That’s what you need. Also note that `gzip` only compresses a single file. It is not an *archiver*. That’s why it’s usually used in concert with `tar`.

Comment: If you run `ldd D0d` you will see all the libs it will need. And the ones you don't have.